# Where can I find an automatic day-night color balance adjuster similar to f.lux/Redshift that works with multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, colors

I tried [f.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/), and I like what it does (automatically adjust the color balance of your monitors depending on time of day), but it seems to work on only 1 of my monitors.

Can I configure it to work on all of them? If not, what other apps can I use that do?

I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with 2 NVIDIA Quadro NVS 420s connected to 4 DELL 2007FPs.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with `-m vidmode` but when I used `-m randr` instead, both monitor changed.

For example, I use:

`gtk-redshift -l 49.2:-123.1 6500:3700  -b 0.7 -g 0.8 -m randr -v`

Answer (score 3):

I tried Redshift, and was able to get it to affect all monitors by running multiple instances targeting specific screens.

Basically I have something like this in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

for i in {0..3} 
do
   redshift -m vidmode:screen=$i -t 5500:4000 &
done
```

There are probably much better ways to accomplish what I need to do, but this seems to work for now.